# Get the source code of a ruby file in the form of a string/text

Tags: ruby

Is there any simple way to get all the source code of a ruby file in the form of a string? I'm looking for something that would behave like `inspect.sourcelines(codeObj)` in python.

Comment: Do you mean the source code of the current file? Or the source code where a given class is defined? Or the source code for a method? Or...?

Comment: have a look at [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) as an `irb` alternative. It offers a method called `show-method` which might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before... But I couldn't find the question on SO anywhere...

```
myCode = File.read(__FILE__)
```

That should do the trick.

`__FILE__` is a special variable which contains the full file path of the currently executing file. Depending how you script is being executed you might be better off using `$0` instead. But this really depends on what you really want.

Comment: So simple, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, I'm new to Ruby and couldn't find a simple answer on SO.